# Single file to retrieve all data from the mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I' ve an html file where each report has been linked to a file that connects to the database and retrieves the specific information. The code is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>2011-2012</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--2011-2012-->
    <h2>2011-2012 Projects</h2>
    <ul id="bullet">

        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_bisense.php">Bisense</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_blood_bms.php">Blood Bank Management System</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_energy_cwn.php">Energy Conservation in wireless networks</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_exam_duty_aec.php">Exam Duty Allocation For End-Users In College</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_farmasoft.php">Farmasoft</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_instant_mu.php">Instant Memo Updater</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_leave_ms.php">Leave Management System</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="y2011_2012/d11_u_drive.php">U Drive - Back Up Storage</a></li><br />
    </ul>
<!--2011-2012 ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see each file is connected to a database file.. For example if the user clicks bisense then he will be forwarded to a page where all the data regarding this report will be displayed.. the php code goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include_once("connection.php"); ?>
<html>                                                                  
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM y2011_2012 WHERE id = \"1\"", $connection);

    if(!$result){
        die("Database query failed: ". mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<head><title>".$row["filename"]."</title></head>";
        echo "<body>";
            echo "<h2><center>".$row["filename"]."</center></h2>";
            echo $row["usn1"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name1"]."<br />";
            echo $row["usn2"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name2"]."<br />";
            echo $row["usn3"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name3"]."<br />";
            echo $row["usn4"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row["name4"]."<br />";
            echo "<h3><center>"."Abstract"."</center></h3>"."<br />";
            echo $row["content"]."<br />";
}
?>

<br /><br />
<center><a href="../../fyproject/2011_2012/bisense/bisense.docx"><img src="../../images/download.gif" alt="download"></a></center>
</body>
<!--2011-2012 ends-->
</html>
```

Similarly for all other file i've specified their id in the link file so that the data is fetched using the id.. that also led me to create multiple files for each link.. Is it possible to achieve the same using one link file which can trace which link was clicked and retrieve the data..?? Or is this code efficient enough?? I'll soon be adding a page where user will be allowed to upload his report in the website and all the details will be fed to the database.. Now at that moment i wont know how to add the name as a link to his report and then when user clicks on that name he ll be directed to his data in the database.. 
For ex: For bisense i created the link and the page but how can i achieve the same for the user uploaded data?? Any help will be much appreciated..

This is the image of my table in the database:
[image: y2011_2012 table in my database]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look at the database `information_schema` in MySQL.

And particulary its table `COLUMNS` which contains all databases, tables, and fields of the MySQL server.

From there you can dynamically find your tables and needed columns to generate what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I din get you.. I am new to php and mysql.. So really sorry for not understanding these technical terms

Comment: In your MySQL server there is a database called "information_schema" and in this database there is a table called COLUMNS. I think it contains what you need.